# Calculation with jquery using Objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, logic

I'm trying to do a calculation, depending on the selects, an example is, calculate the number of adults per a base price.

The problem is that when I select another value in the (Select - Option) it does not update the value and still shows the first value.

Any suggestions?

```js
values = {
    adults : $('#adults').val(),
    children: $('#children').val(),
    listPickup: $('#pickup').val()
}

price = {
    base: values.adults * 6,
    child: values.children * 5,
    pickup: values.listPickup * values.adults,
    total : function() {
    return this.base + this.child + this.pickup
  } 
}

$('.bookinginput').on('change', function(){
    console.log(price.total())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

<select class="bookinginput" name="adults" id="adults" >
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<select class="bookinginput" name="children" id="children" >
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="3">4</option>
</select>
<select class="bookinginput" name="pickup" id="pickup">
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As everybody said, you need to recalculate. Here i did some changes to your code

Basically, every time you call `total()` function, it first call `getProperties()` which is a new method i wrote that gets the current value from the `<select>` objects. Then it gets the total of the updated values

```js
price = {
    base: null,
    child: null,
    pickup: null,
    total : function() {
      // Here we first update the properties with the actual value and then we get the total value
      return this.getProperties().getTotal();
  } ,
  // Get the data from the select and update current price properties
    getProperties: function(){
      this.base = $('#adults').val() * 6;
      this.child = $('#children').val() * 5;
      this.pickup = $('#pickup').val() * $('#adults').val();
      return this;
    },
    // function to get the total value
    getTotal: function(){
      return this.base + this.child + this.pickup;
    }
}

$('.bookinginput').on('change', function(){
    console.log(price.total())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

<select class="bookinginput" name="adults" id="adults" >
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<select class="bookinginput" name="children" id="children" >
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<select class="bookinginput" name="pickup" id="pickup">
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You can explain your code a bit, you left me dumbfounded, hahah ;)

Comment: @JuanDavid Sure, There you got

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to update the values when the onchange event is trigger.
Otherwise, your values are set in the page load but not refresh when you call, for exemple, values.adults.

```
$('.bookinginput').on('change', function(){
    values.adults = $('#adults').val();
    values.children = $('#children').val();
    values.listPickup = $('#pickup').val();
    console.log(price.total())
})
```

Comment: yes but maybe be duplicating the code, the idea is to it reusable. no?